# SELECT TOP 3 Max Score

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question on how to express the output of some results?
The problem is:
There were a number of contests where participants each made number of attempts. The attempt with the highest score is only one considered. Write a query to list the contestants ranked in the top 3 for each contest. If multiple contestants have the same score in each contest, they are at the same rank.

Report event_id, rank 1 name(s), rank 2 name(s), rank 3 name(s). Order the contest by event_id. Name that share a rank should be ordered alphabetically and separated by a comma.

The database consists in only one table is:

| event_id | participant_name | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1434 | Marcos | 9.62821024209408 |
| 1434 | Marcos | 7.30471832966565 |
| 1434 | Vitor | 9.52821024209408 |
| 1434 | Vitor | 6.30471832966565 |

My Query is:

```
WITH max_score AS (
  SELECT event_id, participant_name, CAST(MAX(ROUND(score, 2,1)) AS DECIMAL (18,2)) AS score
  FROM scoretable 
  GROUP BY event_id, participant_name
),
Rank_table AS( 
  SELECT 
       event_id, 
       participant_name,
       score,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER   
        (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY score DESC) AS FinalRank
FROM max_score
)
SELECT * FROM Rank_table
WHERE FinalRank <= 3
ORDER BY event_id, score DESC;
```

| event_id | participant_name | score | FinalRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1434 | Aurora Leedom | 9.98 | 1 |
| 1434 | Shaunta Barletta | 9.88 | 2 |
| 1434 | Tricia Norgard | 9.85 | 3 |
| 2626 | Annita Tessier | 9.95 | 1 |
| 2626 | Loura Fortino, | 9.95 | 1 |
| 2626 | Christinia Padgett | 9.94 | 2 |
| 2626 | Ashlyn Cheatam | 9.72 | 3 |

So I can make the results rank, my question is what resource could I use to make the result look like this:

| event_id | Rank 1 | Rank 2 | Rank 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1434 | Aurora Leedom | Shaunta Barletta | Tricia Norgard |
| 2626 | Annita Tessier, Loura Fortino | Christinia Padgett | Ashlyn Cheatam |

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot query to generate the 3 output columns you want:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY FinalRank) dr
    FROM Rank_table
)

SELECT event_id,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN dr = 1 THEN participant_name END, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY participant_name) AS [Rank 1],
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN dr = 2 THEN participant_name END, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY participant_name) AS [Rank 2],
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN dr = 3 THEN participant_name END, ',')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY participant_name) AS [Rank 3]
FROM cte
ORDER BY event_id;
```

Comment: How does your answer handle "If multiple contestants have the same score in each contest, they are at the same rank." and "Name that share a rank should be ordered alphabetically and separated by a comma."?

Comment: @HABO Sorry, missed that requirement.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Great solution I thought about Pivot but the issue of adding one or more with the same Rank was getting in my way. Your solution really helped me thanks a lot for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL - This worked quite well!

```
WITH MaxScores AS (
    SELECT 
        event_id,
        participant_name,
        MAX(score) AS max_score
    FROM scoretable
    GROUP BY event_id, participant_name
)

, RankedParticipants AS (
    SELECT 
        event_id,
        participant_name,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY max_score DESC) AS dr
    FROM MaxScores
)

SELECT 
    event_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN dr = 1 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name ASC) AS `Rank 1`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN dr = 2 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name ASC) AS `Rank 2`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN dr = 3 THEN participant_name END ORDER BY participant_name ASC) AS `Rank 3`
FROM RankedParticipants
WHERE dr <= 3
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY event_id;
```

Comment: But this question is for SQL Server, not for MySQL. Unless this code is _also_ compatible with TSQL, you're answering a different question than was asked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: scoretable that i used as reference]

```
/* MYSQL SOLUTION */
/* using multiple common table expressions , dense_rank , JOIN and group_concat */

WITH t1 AS
(SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY score DESC) AS 'rk' FROM Scoretable),

t2 AS
(SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE rk<=3),

t3 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=1 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'first' FROM t2 WHERE rk=1 ),

t4 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=2 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'second' FROM t2 WHERE rk=2 ),

t5 AS 
(SELECT event_id , CASE WHEN rk=3 THEN p_Name ELSE NULL END AS 'third' FROM t2 WHERE rk=3 ),

t6 AS 
(SELECT t3.event_id , t3.first , t4.second , t5.third FROM t3 JOIN t4 ON t3.event_id = t4.event_id JOIN t5 ON t4.event_id=t5.event_id ORDER BY 1,2,3,4)

SELECT event_id , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT first) AS 'rank 1' , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT second) AS 'rank 2' , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT third) AS 'rank 3'
FROM t6 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

[image: output]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).